# HTML5 CSS3: <hr> works fine in Chrome. Appears to right of web page in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I upgraded to the most recent version of Firefox, but this is still happening. It works fine in Chrome.  Instead of my horizontal rule appearing near the bottom of the page where it belongs, I have a 1024 pixel line appearing to the right of my web page in firefox.

HTML5:

```css
hr {
  height: 2px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-color: #938FEB;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p/>
  <hr/>
  <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="default.html">Home</a> | <a href="form.html">E-Mail     Form</a> | Calendar |</p>
  <br/>
</footer>
```

I have no clue what's causing this.  Thank you

Comment: why have you set a **px** width to your footer instead of a **100%**?

Comment: Assuming you want a top border on your footer, why don't you add it the way you are supposed to, `border-top: 1px solid #938FEB;` ?

Comment: a opening and closing p-tag seems to be not valid html

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clearer with what you're trying to achieve, also please post jsfiddles so we have something to work from or indent your code.

```css
hr {
  height: 2px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-color: #938FEB;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p/><!--(Not valid)-->
  <hr/>
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="default.html">Home</a> | <a href="form.html">E-Mail Form</a> | Calendar |
  </p>
  <br/>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25zcvws2/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting exact `px` measurements, I think you'd be better either using percentage units, or additionally using calc, both of which are shown below. This way, you'll make your code responsive as well as more efficient by making the following alterations.

- Removed redundant closing p tag
- altered width of both footer and hr element (as described above)
- added a color to footer to allow text elements to appear
- placed text-align property in css
- Added a font coloring to display the other text for demo only (i'm presume this has been left out for demo purposes by OP, i've just added one in)

This can be seen below:

```css
hr {
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(100%-24px);
  border-color: #938FEB;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  color:red;
}
footer p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <hr/>
  <p><a href="default.html">Home</a> | <a href="form.html">E-Mail Form</a> | Calendar |
  </p>
  <br/>
</footer>
```

Comment: Everyone, **thank you** for the suggestions. I tried all of the suggestions from both answers and from the comments. The only thing that had any effect was changing the width of the hr from 1000px to "calc(100%-24px)". This made the hr disappear in Firefox, and there were no changes in Chrome. I'd consider this a partial solution, since the hr is no longer appearing in the wrong place, it's just not appearing at all; and everything is still fine in Chrome. 

I'm still completely open to suggestion as to how to get this hr to show up, and show up in the right place, in Firefox. Thank you.

Comment: @AARRGGHHH: This appears in firefox v.34 on win 8 happily enough for me (as it [should](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)) - Could you possibly remove the width completely, and see if it's showing up? it could be that you have a tag with a higher index overlapping it, or a overflow:hidden attribute set, but I can't tell precisely.